# Connecting Signal Slots using lambda function in for Loop

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I need to add an extra argument to a slot (2 arguments) while connecting with a signal with only one argument for multiple widgets of the same type.
So I created a vector of `Widget` objects, tried making connections using lambda function in a for loop.

Here is an illustration of what I tried :

```
QWidget* widget1, widget2, widget3, widget4;
/*...
Assign memory to them
...*/

QVector <QWidget> m_widgetVec = {widget1, widget2, widget3, widget4}

for(int i=0; i < 4; i++)
{
   connect(m_widgetVec[i], &QWidget::clicked, [&](bool state){
        myfunc(i, state);}));
}
```

When executed values I receive for state is ok, but the value of `i` is always 0.
I expect `i` to be 0,1,2,3. for widgets 1,2,3,4.

Any suggestions?
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your lambda uses capture by reference `[&]`, so the `i` inside the lambda is only a reference to the `for` loop's control variable (and even becomes a dangling reference as soon as the loop terminates). What you want is to capture `i` by value:

```
[i](bool state){myfunc(i, state);}
```

In case `myfunc` is a member of whichever class this is in, you will also need to capture `this`:

```
[i, this](bool state){myfunc(i, state);}
```

Or just capture everything by value:

```
[=](bool state){myfunc(i, state);}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the runtime value of `index` ?

Don't you want to connect `m_widgetVec[i]` instead of `m_widgetVec[index]` ?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo from me, it is indeed m_widgetVec[i] instead of m_widgetVec[index]. Thank you for pointing that out